# Live Photos on android implementation?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-camera

I have come up with a project which implements LIVE Photos capturing on android and I will hopefully make it open sourced,Spoiler : it takes a 1.5 second shot before and after you click the pic and combines them and make the video , While i tried it I was unable to do it with MediaRecorder in android , I even experimented with FFMPEG it just does not works . Anyone has any idea or a little light so i can follow and implement this.My min Api support is 16

Answer (score 0):

Look at this playlist on youtube at episode 18,
taking a photo while recording:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9jCwTXYWjDIHNEGtsRdCTk79I9-95TbJ

I've tried it myself and it worked for video and photo separated but not taking a photo while recording (app crashes).

I hope this will give you a good starting point. By the way, some Android cameras do have that feature inbuilt.